# VSCode Import Quick Fixes always Relative to ${workspaceFolder}

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I'm working on a python project within a pretty large multi-language mono-repo with VSCode's python tools (pylance). The root of the workspace(/repo) is not the root module of python imports.

When attempting to "Quick-Fix" an undefined variable, the language server is able to resolve it and find an import path, but the proposed import is relative to the root of the workspace.

For example, I may be working on a file:

`${workspaceFolder}/backend/src/saasbox/api/auth/serializers.py`

... and need to import something from:

`${workspaceFolder}/backend/src/saasbox/api/modules/identity.py`

... Ideally the proposed import module would be:

`import Thing from saasbox.api.modules.identity`

BUT it is `import Thing from backend.src.saasbox.api.modules.identity`, which isn't what I want. Is there any setting to change this?

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution one:

Add the following configuration in **settings.json** file

```json
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./backend/src"
    ],
```

##### Solution two:

Use VS code to open the **backend** folder instead of the **workspace** folder.

##### Example:

The file structure is as follows

```
workspace
└─ backend
   └─ src
      └─ saasbox
         └─ api
            ├─ auth
            │  └─ serializers.py
            └─ modules
               └─ identity.py
```

---

Now use VS code to open the **workspace** folder, add the above configuration to **settings.json**, and get the quick import as follows

[image]

---

If I use vsod to open **backend** as a workspace (remove the config just added), the resulting imports are as follows

[image]

[image]

**Why is the import that opens `backend` as workspace not including `src`?**

**src** is a special folder, and there is a default enabled setting in VS code to add **src** to the import path.

[image]

*So the second solution above could also be:*

*Move the **src** folder under the current workspace, making it the first level folder under the workspace.*

[image]

Comment: adding `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` does not seem to work.

Comment: How it doesn't work, can you elaborate? Just saying it doesn't work, is it making me guess what you did and what you got?

Comment: I've added that configuration, and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. I added the config and it worked. What do you think is the use of saying that. How to solve the problem if details cannot be provided.